# Is the definition of stabilizer given at Planet Math really the currently accepted definition among group theorists?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

According to [Planet Math](http://planetmath.org/stabilizer), given

1. a group $G$
2. a set $X$
3. a subset $S \subseteq X$
4. and a group action $G \times X \rightarrow X,$

then the *stabilizer* of $S$ is define to be: $\{g \in G \mid gS \subseteq S\}.$

I have an issue with this definition; I think the condition $gS \subseteq S$ should be replaced by $gS = S.$ (Essentially, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Fixed_points_and_stabilizer_subgroups) only defines stabilizers when $S$ is a a singleton set, thereby avoiding this issue. [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stabilizer+group) also goes this way.)

To see the problem, let $X$ denote the real line, and write $G$ for the group of automorphisms of $X$ (i.e. order-preserving bijections from $X$ back to itself). Let $S = [-1,1]$. Then according to Planet Math, the function

$$g : x \in X \mapsto x/2 \in X$$

is in the stabilizer of $S$. But this seems odd, because the restriction of the above function to a mapping $S \rightarrow S$ does not yield a bijection. The problem, of course, is that $gS = [-1/2,1/2]$ is a proper subset of $S = [-1,1]$. Anyway, my question is:

> **Question.** Is the definition of stabilizer given at Planet Math really the currently accepted definition among group theorists?

Comment: as with any terminology that sometimes varies, if an explicit definition is not given in an article you are reading, look for evidence in context. I can see how usage might vary among disciplines.

Comment: There's two I've used in the past: the pointwise stabilizer defined as $\{g \in G:gs=s \text{ for all } s \in S\}$ and the setwise stabilizer defined as $\{g \in G:gS=S\}$.  I think it's a bug: in the example $g^{-1}:x \mapsto 2x$ is not in the stabilizer, so it's not even a group.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones, right, exactly; its not even a group!

Comment: setwise stabilizer of $\Delta\subseteq X$ is defined by $$G_{\{\Delta\}}=\{x\in G\mid\Delta ^x= \Delta\}$$ (by Dixon's Permutation Groups book)

Comment: There's indeed possible ambiguity because usually to say that $S$ is $g$-stable means $gS\subset S$ and $g$-invariant means $gS=S$ (this is far from universal though), but even with this convention, when $G$ acts on the power set of $X$, the stabilizer of the point $S$ of the power set is the set of $g$ such that $gS=S$. I think the latter definition is the most common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a typo or sloppiness, since David Jao claims that the stabilizer is a subgroup, and it is not a subgroup with his "definition." The correct definition would require the equality, not the containment. I like the French terminology, where the "fixator" is used for the pointwise stabilizer of the subset.